# SP2013 - Adding title and border (Chrome Type) to a search web part

Tags: style

I have a page in which all the web parts have titles and borders (Chrome Type).
Adding a search box web part causes all other web part borders to disappear.
Does anyone know how this behavior can be fixed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the exact color and type of the default SharePoint borders:

```
.ms-WPBorder, .ms-WPBorderBorderOnly
{ 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
     padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the search webpart has something which is breaking or overriding the other styles of the page, hence I applied a simple fix by adding a content editor to the page with the following css:

```
<style type="text/css">.ms-WPBorder, .ms-WPBorderBorderOnly{ border-color:black; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;} </style>
```